# Nhibernate: using Expression

Tags: nhibernate

Using nHibernate, I would like to query on an integer datatype, but its always returning the exact match.

How could I write an expression that returns a list starting with the number entered?

right now I am using it as:
(clientNum is a long)

```
crit.Add(Expression.Like("ClientNumber", clientNum)); //this always gives me exact matches only
```

so I tried the following, but its complainging of a wroing type (its only expecting a string)

```
crit.Add(Expression.Like("ClientNumber", clientNum, MatchMode.Start));
```

Update: Also I tried the clientNum.ToString() but I get a db exception saying invalid type.

I can use the sql as follows to get what I want, but how do I do this in nHibernate??

```
SELECT * FROM ClientTable
WHERE clientNum LIKE '3%' --incase I wanted a list that starts with 3...
```

Comment: I suppose that ClientNumber is stored as string on the database, right?

Comment: No, it is stored as a numeric value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure about the .NET version, but hybernate supported limited casting (e.g. *cast (... as ...)*) in HQL. I think you would need to cast the value to a string and then apply your '*Like*' clause.  Should be able to do this all in HQL. Alternatively, you can do it using the SQL Expressions (ex. *Expression.Sql(...)*) and do the same thing using T-SQL.

Comment: Something like `from Client where cast(clientNum as string) like '3%'`

Comment: @Jamie, I am not sure how to use your example,  is it with Expression or Restriction or sql?
Besides the number I want to query is not hardcoded it is passed into the method as a param., what do I do then?

Comment: It is an Expression. You can build the actual sql string in the Expression dynamically... For Example `Expression.Sql(new SqlString(string.format("cast(clientNum as string) like '{0}%'", param)))`. Check the overloads and use the one that fits your needs.

Comment: Expression.Sql(new SqlString(string.format("clientNum like '{0}%'" -did the trick for me. clientNum is stored as a numeric on the db. Thanks.